# How to Refresh the Start Screen?

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, start-screen, total-commander, tiles

Over Four Years have passed since we have installed the First Update that has brought *Windows* *10* into our world and still there are things out there that are not working properly.

First of all, we have decided to give up using Desktop Icons at all. We have a Very Nice Green and Empty Slate.

[image: A Very Relaxing Desktop]

This has been achieved by simply disabling the Display of the Desktop Icons. Also, there are no Desktop Icons stored even on the Hard-Disk.

[image: A Very Clean Desktop Folder]

Also, the Task-Bar is set to be Automatically Hidden.

The *Pinned Tiles* Section of the *Start Screen* have also been all removed, giving a Very Relaxing and Empty Effect.

[image: No _Pinned Tiles_ in the _Start Screen_]

In the *All Apps* Section of the *Start Screen* we are finding our Tiles:

[image: A Fragment of the _All Apps_ Section of the _Start Screen_]

Now, in the *Web-Browsers_-_Google_Chrome* Folder, we can see only Two Tiles: *Google Chrome* and *Google Drive*.

This is actually a Great Thing, because we *do* see something down there.

But when we are looking on the Hard-Disk, we are shocked to find also Three Other ShortCuts that are not visible in the *Start Screen*: *Google Docs.lnk*, *Google Sheets.lnk*, and *Google Slides.lnk*. This is not so cool.

[image: Three Little Missing ShortCuts on the Hard-Disk]

Now, someone would venture into asking: how to refresh the *Start Screen*? We do not want to restart its Process. Even after the Whole Restart of the Machine, still those Three Little ShortCuts are not read from the Hard-Disk.

Has anybody hit this Issue before?

***UPDATE*:**

@Gen Test was actually right.

Billions of Little Gizmos have appeared during the Latest Twenty-Seven Years since we have started fiddling around the Home Personal Computer.

`"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Web-Browsers_-_Google_Chrome\Google Chrome.lnk"` points to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`

`"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Web-Browsers_-_Google_Chrome\Google Drive.lnk"` points to `D:\G\Root\OneDrive`

`"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Web-Browsers_-_Google_Chrome\Google Docs.lnk"` points to `"C:\Program Files\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe" --new_document`

`"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Web-Browsers_-_Google_Chrome\Google Sheets.lnk"` points to `"C:\Program Files\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe" --new_spreadsheet`

`"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Web-Browsers_-_Google_Chrome\Google Slides.lnk"` points to `"C:\Program Files\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe" --new_presentation`

Now, the Question still remains: how does the "*Google Drive*" manage to remove Three ShortCuts?

Comment: Are those shortcuts pointing to the same chrome.exe but use different arguments? Windows 10's start menu will filter out shortcut copies that point to the same target.

Comment: Only one of the Five ShortCuts points to `chrome.exe`, @Gen Test. The only pointer that I can give to you and to anybody else who might be interested in solving this Little Issue is the fact that the `Web-Browsers_-_Google_Chrome` Folder has been manually created and all of the Five Little ShortCuts have manually been moved in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I have finally nailed this issue.

The three aforementioned short-cuts referring all to the *Google* web-applications are all referencing the `C:\Program Files\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe` executable binary file.

Somehow, the forth aforementioned short-cut refers to the `D:\G\Root\OneDrive` folder path and yet it is looking for icons in the same `%ProgramFiles%\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe` executable binary file.

So, somehow, starting from @Gen Test's original comment, the reason for removing three short-cuts from the resulting *Start screen* folder must be related to their belonging to the same executable binary file.

This leads to the apparently stunning couple of tiles formed only by the *Google* *Chrome* tile and by the *Google* *Drive* tile.

***Update***: In the meantime, things have got even clearer.

The three short-cuts that I have mentioned above were also present in the `Cloud_Providers_-_Backup_and_Sync_from_Google` folder.

After I have removed them from there, they have mysteriously appeared back where I was expecting them to be, namely in the `Web-Browsers_-_Google_Chrome` folder.

So, indeed, the *Start screen* removes duplicates even between different folders.

[image: Refreshed Start screen folder]